# file not found when installing brother printer

Tags: drivers, printing, brother

I am on day 2 of Linux Ubuntu after 20 years of Windows. I am having to learn fast but obviously a complete newbie. So far, I'm a convert! Just a little help with this driver for my Brother printer.

So, I downloaded the linux deb driver from the brother website. I installed gunzip (i think) and re-booted the computer. I then tried again to install the driver - but it keeps telling me that there is no such file... What am i doing wrong?

```
brendan@BrendanPC:~$ cd Downloads
brendan@BrendanPC:~/Downloads$ ls
linux-brprinter-installer-2.2.2-1
brendan@BrendanPC:~/Downloads$ gunzip linux-brprinter-installer-2.2.2-1.gz
gzip: linux-brprinter-installer-2.2.2-1.gz: No such file or directory
```

Any advice, preferably very basic, would be great!
Brendan

Comment: To see what type of file `linux-brprinter-installer-2.2.2-1` is, you can use the command `file linux-brprinter-installer-2.2.2-1` and it'll tell you if it's a directory, text file, or other (not by the filename, but using the contents inside the file so wrongly named files get ignored).  Your `gunzip` command is for a different filename (ending in ".gz" where you `ls` command showed it didn't have that filename (or extension; officially an extension is still part of the filename))

Comment: My Brother Printer, just worked. https://wiki.debian.org/CUPSDriverlessPrinting Even booting live installer in live mode, added printer before I had a chance to do much.

Answer (score 0):

Not to deter you from anything that has been already discussed, because there is WAAAAY more benefit in learning what you did wrong there(for a new learner)... and not to mention it's a more up-to-date method than what I'm about to suggest

.... but if `cups` is installed and running on your machine. You should be able to open a browser and go to http://127.0.0.1:631 and it will take you to the CUPS configuration page.

Under Administration - you can install printers, and for me looking at a version of ubuntu MATE 20.04 that I've barely interacted with... There is a full compliment of "Brother" printer drivers pre-loaded. (And there may be more available from ubuntu's repository via the apt installer)

[image]

This is the very old method of doing it, but it is "very basic".... I still use it because it's not something I need to deal with more than once per install.... downside to that; I think I discovered this around 2006, I never bothered learning any other method... Don't be like this me